# How to disable android studio unit tests (androidTest)

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, android-studio

I have imported an eclipse project into android studio

Somehow it figured out that another one of my eclipse projects contained unit-test code for the imported project

It brought in that code and put it in a src/androidTest dir

I didn't really want it to do that but they are there now and causing the build to fail

Is there a means to turn off the androidTest stuff? So I can concentrate on whether the app actually builds?

Maybe its via a gradle setting? (This is my first exposure to gradle)

Maybe I just need to delete all the androidTest java files but this seems a bit final..

Comment: What you _can_ do as a workaround is to build your app by going to "Gradle projects" -> ":app" (or how your app directory calls) -> "build". It'll compile you an apk.  (or create "Android Application" configuration with default params and proper module - and then run it, instead of fully rebuilding/making the whole project). I.e. the idea is to avoid building whole project, unless you actually need it, but building the app.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to delete all files, you can just rename "androidTest" folder to something like "_androidTest" and they won't show up in Project anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you do Rebuilding the project in Android Studio - all the source files in the project are recompiled. Plenty of different tasks start including `:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac` which is causing the build-break, once your Instrumental Tests are not compilable.

[image]

Calling for rebuilding in Android Studio is just a UI for passing these tasks to gradle:

> Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources,
>   :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar,
>   :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources,
>   :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]

I.e. there's no obvious way how can it be modified.

**Workarounds:**

- comment out broken files in *androidTest*
- remove/rename *androidTest* directory
- build project with *[Android plugin for Gradle](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html)* and passing all commands, apart from ones related to InstrumentalTests
- avoid Making/Rebuilding solution, just add(if it's not exist yet) Android Application configuration and build the app itself, without instrumental tests

I hope, it helps.

Comment: went with prepending an _ to androidTest. Couldn't see how to rename the dir within android studio so I did it in emacs

Answer (score 17):

Put this code into your app's gradle script:

```
tasks.configureEach { task ->
    if (task.name.equals("lint")) {
        //this is for speed up build
        task.enabled = false
    }
    if (task.name.contains("Test")) {
        //this is what you need
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

When gradle add a task, this code ll check tasks name.
if this task is 'lint' ([check here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html)) which is not need every build.
if this task has a 'Task' word, we can skip if we want.

```
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild SKIPPED
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl SKIPPED
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest SKIPPED
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript SKIPPED
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig SKIPPED
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues SKIPPED
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources SKIPPED
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources SKIPPED
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebugAndroidTest SKIPPED
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources SKIPPED
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources SKIPPED
```

I dont know what these tasks are. But when i skip on my project doesnt effect anything but speed (not much because i dont have test files) which is a pain on gradle build system.

I hope, this ll help you.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue. Please update your answer to explain how this improves on the other accepted and upvoted answers this question already has. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm new to gradle. Also my english is not enough to tell the details. I am getting help from the site all the time. I thought it might help someone, somehow. I can delete it if you want.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer! Don't worry about your English, other users can edit it to improve the text as long as we understand what you re trying to explain :)

Comment: very bad way :) what about any other not "Test" tasks cases :) like project name contains names "Test + post ", "Pre + test", "pre + test +  post"?

Answer (score 7):

Someone might find this useful: If you're using `JUnit` there's an `@Ignore` command you can put on a test method to ignore the entire test method.

**Example:**

```
@Ignore("This test will be ignored")
@Test
public void my_test_method() {
    // test code here...
}
```